# Firebase and Swift After Facebook Login and current user

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase

I am new to Swift and Firebase. I am trying to build an app with a facebook login. I have implement some code and try to learn for the tutorial but I am not really understand that how the login can be save and "know" the current user data. So i tried to implement this code in the login method and to save the user id
 `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result ["uid"], forKey: "uid")`

and this:

```
 var REF_USER_CURRENT: Firebase {
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String
    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(baseUrl)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)
    return currentUser!
}
```

After the login it will move to other view and display the user name. I use this code to retrieve the username data

```
   func displayName()  {

    FirebaseHelper.fbh.REF_USER_CURRENT.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        let currentUser = snapshot.value.objectForKey("name") as! String
        self.currentUsername = currentUser
        self.facebookUserName.text = currentUser as String
        print("Username: \(currentUser)")
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })

}
```

However, every time i logged in and it will show this error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** with highlighting the REF_USER_CURRENT. I think the reason is because it cannot probably save the uid in NSUserDefault. It is my login method

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error != nil{
        print("Facebook login failed. Error \(error)")
    }else if result.isCancelled {
        print("Facebook login was cancelled")
    }else if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){
          let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        FirebaseHelper.fbh.REF_BASE.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

            if(error != nil){
                print("Login failed. \(error)")
            }else{
                print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                self.saveUserToFirebase(authData)
                print("User Saved Successfully! \(authData.uid)")
                self.processLogin(accessToken, authData: authData)
                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileSetup") as! UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }

        })
    }

}

   func processLogin(accessToken: String, authData: FAuthData) {
    FirebaseHelper.fbh.REF_USER_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("fail")
        } else {
            print("no")
        }
    })
}


private func createUser(authData: FAuthData!){

    let displayName = authData.providerData["displayName"] as! String
    let email = authData.providerData["email"] as! String
    var imageUrl = ""

    if let url = authData.providerData["profileImageURL"] as? String {
        imageUrl = url
    }

    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: ["fields": "url", "redirect": false, "type": "large"], HTTPMethod: nil)
    request.startWithCompletionHandler { connection, result, facebookerror in

        if facebookerror != nil{
            print("Graph API Call failed. \(facebookerror)")
        }else{

            //let userData = (result as! NSDictionary).copy()

            let user = ["name": displayName, "email": email,"profilePicUrl": imageUrl]
            FirebaseHelper.fbh.createFirebaseUser(authData.uid, user: user)
            if facebookerror != nil{
                print("Error occured! \(facebookerror)")
            }else{
                print("User Saved Successfully! \(authData.uid) \(displayName)")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(result ["uid"], forKey: "uid")


            }
            self.facebookLoginBtn.hidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

I don't understand how the NSUserdafult will work for current user and do i need to write any code in each page to check the current user data to retrieve the data? Please modify my code for more understanding in this issue.

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to authenticate a user, and if that is successful, store their login credentials locally on the device, it's pretty straightforward.

The login process varies a bit by provider (make sure it's enabled in your Firebase dashboard) but they all have the same flow.

Once authenticated, authData variable contains information about that specific user. The uid property on the FAuthData object is how you uniquely identify the user.

```
let email = "dude@thing.com"
let pw = "password"

ref.authUser(email, pw) {
    error, authData in

    if error != nil {
        // eh, something went wrong, handle it

    } else {

       let myAppData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       myAppData.setValue(auth.uid, forKey: "uid")
       myAppData.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
       myAppData.setValue(pw, forKey: "password")
    }
}
```

Moving on from that, you will probably want to create a /users node within Firebase that contains other information about the user

```
users
  uid_0
   name: "Pete"
   shoe_size: "13"
  uid_1
   name: "Larry"
   shoe_size: "2"
```

You can find a lot more information on this topic on the Firebase guide in the [User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html) section, along with sample code.